# Connect to a Windows Server 2008R2 using php, ldap, tls fails if server has NPS service

Tags: windows-server-2008, php, ldap, tls, nps

### Servers:

- `DALCON2` (Windows 2008R2, DC, NPS)
- `DALCON3` (Windows 2008R2, DC)
- `DALCON-WWW` (Ubuntu server)

### Goal:

From `DALCON-WWW`, using adLDAP with TLS to connect to a domain controller LDAP service

If I connect to `DALCON2`, I get: `Server returned an error: [2] ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Server is unavailable`. If I connect do `DALCON3`, it works.

`DALCON2` has a `Network Policy Service (NPS)` enabled to manage VPN connections. Nothing is specificly "denied" in the policies. The LDAP port is open and will respond if not using TLS, but it's unusable (stronger authentification required). I didn't find anything related to LDAP or TLS in NPS.

What might be wrong with `DALCON2` that I can't connect to it?

**edit**

I got more debug infos:

Warning: ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Server is unavailable in /var/www/dalcon-inc.com/dev/test/test_ldap.php on line 12

Error Binding to LDAP: 00002028: LdapErr: DSID-0C0901FC, comment: The server requires binds to turn on integrity checking if SSL\TLS are not already active on the connection, data 0, v1db1

**edit**

in the Group Policy Management Editor: Computer Configuration, Policies, Windows Settings, Security Settings, and Local Policies, and then click Security Options.
In the right pane, double-click the Domain Controller: LDAP server signing requirements policy.

while setting it to "none", 
`DALCON2`:
Plain: OK
SSL: Error Binding to LDAP: Error in the push function. / A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.
TLS: Warning: ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Server is unavailable

`DALCON3`
Plain: OK
SSL: OK
TLS: OK

** edit**

`DALCON3` is an exchange 2010 server with a valid SSL certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

I had to install my SSL certificate in IIS on `DALCON2`. I exported it from `DALCON3` in .pfx format and imported it back. `iisreset` et voilà!

Comment: Nice find, that is certainly a bitch to track down.